# "Bag of characters" n-grams in R

Tags: r, machine-learning, nlp, tokenize, n-gram

I would like to create a Term document matrix containing character n-grams. For example, take the following sentence:

"In this paper, we focus on a different but simple text representation."

Character 4-grams would be: |In_t|, |n_th|, |_thi|, |this|, |his__|, |is_p|, |s_pa|, |_pap|, |pape|, |aper|, etc.

I have used the R/Weka package to work with "bag of words" n-grams, but I'm having difficulty adapting tokenizers such as the one below to work with characters:

```
BigramTokenizer <- function(x){
    NGramTokenizer(x, Weka_control(min = 2, max = 2))}

tdm_bigram <- TermDocumentMatrix(corpus,
                                 control = list(
                                 tokenize = BigramTokenizer, wordLengths=c(2,Inf)))
```

Any thoughts on how to use R/Weka or an other package to create character n-grams?

Comment: If you don't mind me asking. Why would you need to do this?

Comment: @SunilDS it's an effective technique for certain problems. Here  is an example of it's use in a [Kaggle competition](http://blog.kaggle.com/2012/09/26/impermium-andreas-blog/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the `CharacterNGramTokenizer` instead.
The `NGramTokenizer` splits on characters like spaces.

```
##########
### the following lines are mainly a one to one copy from RWeka.
### Only hardocded CharacterNGramTokenizer is new
library(rJava)


CharacterNGramTokenizer <- structure(function (x, control = NULL) 
{
  tokenizer <- .jnew("weka/core/tokenizers/CharacterNGramTokenizer")
  x <- Filter(nzchar, as.character(x))
  if (!length(x)) 
    return(character())
  .jcall("RWekaInterfaces", "[S", "tokenize", .jcast(tokenizer, 
                                                     "weka/core/tokenizers/Tokenizer"), .jarray(as.character(control)), 
         .jarray(as.character(x)))
}, class = c("R_Weka_tokenizer_interface", "R_Weka_interface"
), meta = structure(list(name = "weka/core/tokenizers/NGramTokenizer", 
                         kind = "R_Weka_tokenizer_interface", class = "character", 
                         init = NULL), .Names = c("name", "kind", "class", "init")))
### copy till here
###################

BigramTokenizer <- function(x){
    CharacterNGramTokenizer(x, Weka_control(min = 2, max = 2))}
```

Sadly it is not included in RWeka by default.
However, if you want to use weka this seems to be a kind of holistic version

Answer (score 4):

I find `quanteda` quite useful:

```
library(tm)
library(quanteda)
txts <- c("In this paper.", "In this lines this.")
tokens <- tokenize(gsub("\\s", "_", txts), "character", ngrams=4L, conc="")
dfm <- dfm(tokens)
tdm <- as.TermDocumentMatrix(t(dfm), weighting=weightTf)
as.matrix(tdm)
#       Docs
# Terms  text1 text2
#   In_t     1     1
#   n_th     1     1
#   _thi     1     2
#   this     1     2
#   his_     1     1
#   is_p     1     0
#   s_pa     1     0
#   _pap     1     0
#   pape     1     0
#   aper     1     0
#   per.     1     0
#   is_l     0     1
#   s_li     0     1
#   _lin     0     1
#   line     0     1
#   ines     0     1
#   nes_     0     1
#   es_t     0     1
#   s_th     0     1
#   his.     0     1
```

Comment: I had trouble with this solution. It may be valid but using the sample data about I get an error: `tokens <- tokenize(gsub("\\s", "_", txts), "character", ngrams=4L, conc="")` Error in if (simplify) return(unlist(result, use.names = FALSE)) else return(result) : 
  argument is not interpretable as logical